# How did my JavaScript code get an undefined result?

Tags: javascript, object

I was practicing creating an object in JS and created the following object:

```js
const jonas = {
    firstName: 'Jonas',
    lastName: 'Schmedtmann',
    birthYear: 1991,
    job: 'teacher',
    friends: ['Michael', 'Peter', 'Steven'],
    hasDriversLicense: false,

    calcAge: function () {
        this.age = 2037 - this.birthYear;
        return this.age;
    },
  };
```

A strange thing happen when I want to print the output of the function `calcAge` with the following code:

```js
console.log(jonas.age);
```

The browser outputs "undefined" for the `console.log()` command.

Can anyone tell me where I got it wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: have you executed `jonas.calcAge()` before the `console.log`

Comment: @lastr2d2 Thanks. I have solved this with your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const jonas = {
    firstName: 'Jonas',
    lastName: 'Schmedtmann',
    birthYear: 1991,
    job: 'teacher',
    friends: ['Michael', 'Peter', 'Steven'],
    hasDriversLicense: false,

    calcAge: function () {
        this.age = 2037 - this.birthYear;
        return this.age;
    },
  };
```

here `calcAge` is a function declaration that will add age property to the object by accessing the `birthYear` property of the same object.
Everything sounds good but this all going to happen only if the function is `called/executed`.

`function declaration` and `function call/execution` is two different thing. so the console output is `undefined` as the function is never called

so need to call the function

```
jonas.calcAge()
```

Comment: Thank you. This is solved. I learnt a lot!

Answer (score 0):

`console.log(jonas.calcAge());`  will give you the value of age

***or***

```
jonas.age = jonas.calcAge();
```

***then***

```
console.log(jonas.age);
```

Comment: Thank you. My problem is solved. Learnt a lot!